# ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor view not recognizing Dropdownlistfor HTML Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I am trying to add a dropdownlist to a strongly typed razor view. ASP.Net MVC 4.0, Razor View engine version 2.0.0.0

```
@using System;
@model SampleApp.Models.ServiceRequestModel

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "ServiceRequest";
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.CategoryID, Model.Categories)
```

and the Model is as below:

```
public class ServiceRequestModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public SelectList Category { get; set; }
}
```

it is always showing an error in intellisense in CSHTML file as:

> System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and no extension method 'DropDownListFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and also it is giving errors for :

> Error  3   The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

I have checked the web.config in View folder:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem yet?

Comment: Yes this is solved. The line for Host factory in the above config is pointing to a wrong version , it should be 3.0.0.0 as below:            <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

Comment: Would you mind providing this as an answer? It will help the users with similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below line of config code had to be changed to 4.0.0.0

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, **Version=3.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

**changed to**

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, **Version=4.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent over a day on this error and it ended up being a data type clash with the VM data source for the dropdownlist (ie it wasn't a list of type IEnumerable). For some reason VS2012 thought the error was with the namespace even though it appeared in Intellipath.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue (only with html.displayFor).

I'm not sure how it started but i solved it by replacing the following:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

with

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
</appSettings>
```

in the View folder's Web.config file.

Found my solution [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18612)